# jQuery .hover() strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create an image gallery with `HTML`, `CSS` & `jQuery`. I created a `div` which appears when my mouse enters on another `div`. But when my mouse enters on the `div`, the other `div` appears one time, disappears, and then appears again.  How do I fix this?

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    // stock dans des variables
    var dark = $('.hov');
    var img = $('img');

    // cacher les hover
    dark.hide();

    // montrer au survol de l'image
        img.mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).next().fadeIn('slow');
        });
        img.mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).next().fadeOut('slow');
        }); 
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250">
                <div class="hov"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250">
                <div class="hov"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250">
                <div class="hov"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide some fiddle with this case for us?

Comment: I guess showing the next element overlap the one you are hovering which then fire the mouseleave event and then fire the mouseenter event once next element hidden again, and so on... Provide relevant CSS too. Anyway, you should just bind these events to `.col-md-4` container level

Comment: Excuse me, I don't understand your question !

Comment: @AntoninMrchd Go to https://jsfiddle.net/ and paste in all of your `HTML`, `CSS` and `jQuery` and send us a link to it so we can see it running and have everything we need to try and help you diagnose your problem.

Comment: Here is : https://jsfiddle.net/h2xzb4oj/#&togetherjs=2O7HVoM5ch

Comment: Or here is : https://jsfiddle.net/h2xzb4oj/

Comment: @AntoninMrchd check my answer. Is this what u expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try this:
https://jsfiddle.net/km3ewek5/1/

(Note the `mouseleave` is on the `dark` element)

```
$(function(){
    // stock dans des variables
    var dark = $('.hov');
    var img = $('img');

    // cacher les hover
    dark.hide();

    // montrer au survol de l'image
        img.mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).next().fadeIn('slow');
        });
        dark.mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).fadeOut('slow');
        }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attaching the `mouseleave` event to the wrong element. So change

```
    img.mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).next().fadeIn('slow');
    });
    img.mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).next().fadeOut('slow');
    });
```

to

```
  img.mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).next().fadeIn('slow').mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    });
  });
```

```js
$(function() {
  // stock dans des variables
  var dark = $('.hov');
  var img = $('img');

  // cacher les hover
  dark.hide();

  // montrer au survol de l'image
  img.mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).next().fadeIn('slow').mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
 html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.col-md-4 {
  padding: 0;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
hr {
  width: 70%;
}
img {
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.hov {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  height: 250px;
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <h1> Ma gallerie photo </h1>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250">
          <div class="hov"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250">
          <div class="hov"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250">
          <div class="hov"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250">
          <div class="hov"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250">
          <div class="hov"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250">
          <div class="hov"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```